# Full list of CAS numbers?

Tags: software, databases

I'm trying to find a full list of CAS Registry Numbers, but it looks like it's not in open access.
Is it a proprietary database that can't be downloaded easily?

Comment: You may find CAS#s by typing individual chemicals you are interested in. Any vendor catalog such as Sigma-Aldrich provides long list of chemicals and their CAS#s.

Comment: CAS.org is the entity in charge of the registry. Various places to find numbers are shown on the FAQ page (https://www.cas.org/support/documentation/chemical-substances/faqs). They put time and effort into keeping the database and entering new compounds.